# UWP Show a check symbol when boolean is true

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a ListView with all kind of tasks that have to be completed. When a task is completed a user presses on the item in the listview. This changes a boolean in my web api. Now I want to display a check symbol on the items that are already completed when I get all the items from my API.

```
<SymbolIcon Grid.Column="0" x:Name="CompleteTask" Symbol="Accept"/>
<TextBlock Name="TaakNaam" 
    Grid.Column="1"
    Text="{x:Bind TaskName}" 
    FontSize="16"/>
```

[What it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BVH9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created this Converter:

```
public class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public BooleanToVisibilityConverter()
    {
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value is bool && (bool) value)
        {
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }
        return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return (value is Visibility && (Visibility)value == Visibility.Visible);
    }
}
```

And imported this in my view:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <vm:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis" />
</Page.Resources>
```

Than I added a binding to my SymbolIcon:

```
<SymbolIcon Grid.Column="0" x:Name="CompleteTask" Symbol="Accept" Foreground="Green" Visibility="{Binding Path=Check, Converter=StaticResource BoolToVis}}"/>
```

Source: https://pmdevweb.wordpress.com/2016/05/24/uwp-binding-boolean-to-visibility/

Answer (score 1):

you can write property

```
public Visibility TickVisibility
{
    get {return YourBoolean == true ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;}
}
```

and Bind it:

```
<SymbolIcon Grid.Column="0" x:Name="CompleteTask" Symbol="Accept" Visibility={Binding TickVisibility}/>
```

or use NotifyProperty every time YourBoolean has changed
or write Converter that will implement IValueConverter and will convert bool<=>Visibility

Comment: The OP is using `x:Bind`. What's the reason to use `Binding` instead (if any)?

Comment: Actually there should be no difference (in this case there won't be). It can be chaged to x:Bind, but I personally prefer Binding - because it is more relevant and looks better with NVVM.

Comment: There are significant differences. For one, `x:Bind` and `Binding` cannot be used interchangeably. For another, they have different default modes. Last, but certainly not least, `x:Bind` is checked at compile time, producing a compiler error (whereas `Binding` will fail at runtime ). See [Data binding in depth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth) for details. You have to have a **very good** reason to choose `Binding` over `x:Bind` (*personal preference* isn't a good reason).

Comment: "you have to have a very good reason to choose Binding over x:Bind" oh, please don't make me laugh, for me if Binding works everytime and under every condition - it is enough, the only TRUE advantage of x:Bind is that it is being checked at compile time. Disadvantages are stronger - default OneTime setting that I need to change almost every time to OneWay, need to use UpdateBindings(), the need to have ViewModel reference in the code behind, the need to have ObjectToObject converter and so on. Trust me, I've been there. Feel much better with Binding

Comment: ps. x:Bind does not event have UpdateSourceTrigger like Binding and I don't have time to pass a limitation that x:Bind forces me to pass while I can use Binding istead and have it out of the box.

Comment: *"the only TRUE advantage of x:Bind is that it is being checked at compile time"* - It is checked at compile time, because it does get **compiled**. So, improved performance is another *"TRUE advantage"*. And having to change defaults is not a disadvantage, maybe a minor inconvenience, although I do like to read explicit code anyway. No second-guessing an author's intent when they left out an optional item, whether they were aware of the default value or not.